# How can I run a code directly into a processor with a File System?

Tags: c++, filesystems, fpga

I have a simple anisotropic filter c/c++ code that will process an .pgm image which is an text file with greyscale information for each pixel, and after done processing, it will generate an  output image with the filter applied.

This program takes up to some seconds in order for it to do about 10 iterations on a x86 CPU running windows.

Me and an academic finishing his master degree on applied computing, we need to run the code under FPGA (Altera DE2-115) to see if there is considerable results of performance gain when running the code directly on the processor (NIOS 2).

We have successfully booted up the S.O uClinux under the FPGA, but there are some errors with device hardware, and by that we can't access SD-Card not even Ethernet, so we can't get the code and image into the FPGA in order to test its performance.

So I am here asking to an alternative way to test our code performance directly into an CPU with a file system so the code can read the image and generate another one.

The alternative can be either with an product that has low cost and easy to use (I was thinking raspberry PI), or either if I could upload the code somewhere that runs automatically for me and give me the reports.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

what you're trying to do is benchmarking some software on a multi GHz x86 Processor vs. a soft-core processor running 50MHz? (as much as I can tell from Altera docs)
I can guarantee that it will be even slower on the FPGA! Since it is also running an OS (even embedded Linux) it also has threading overhead and what not. This can not be considered running it "directly" on CPU (whatever you mean by this)

If you really want to leverage the performance of an FPGA you should "convert" your C-Code into a HDL and run it directly in hardware. Accessing the data should be possible. I don't know how it's done with an Altera board but Xilinx has some libraries accessing data from a SD card with FAT.

Comment: We know it will be slower when running on the "soft-core processor", but our goal is to split the code into several small processing pieces that might result in parallelism on the code, what we expect to happen is to process lots of pixels per clock pulse, that will be the "gain" i'am talking about, sorry that I wasn't that specific before.

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa: doing a lot in parallel on an FPGA makes sense -- but you *won't* get it by using a NIOS. It features *some* parallel execution, but only on the order of 1.1-1.2 instructions per clock cycle.

Comment: so if it's just about benchmarking, why not loading the image into the program (as an static char[] for example)? if you want to parallelize it you will need some initial module where the data is anyway. you can then run it in parallel by pipelining to other processors or distributing some chunks of the date to them

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I think they're talking about a MPSoC here, not about a single processor

Answer (score 1):

You can use on board SRAM or DDR2 RAM to run OS and your application. 
Hardware design in your FPGA must have memory controller in it. In SOPC or Qsys select external memory as reset vector and compile design.

Then open NioSII build tools for Eclipse. 
In Eclipse create new project by selecting NiosII Application and BSP project.
Once the project is created, go to BSP properties and type offset of external memory in the linker tab and generate BSP.
Compile project and Run as Nios II hardware. 
This will run you application on through external memory.
You wont be able to see the image but 2-D array representing image in memory can be
printed on console.